# Querying database without using echo, producing results for design

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

there's something that's giving me a bit of a headache at the moment. I am querying a database retrieving some data after clicking a link from a previous page.

Easy enough I get to play about with some code in the 'echo'. Problem is in the ‘echo’ as I need to put in php includes and general html/design code for design purposes. Is there a way or a method where I can write the code but then call variables again later and have the ability to place other php code such as includes? Basically something which is going to let me have to have the code but then allow me to concentrate on the design aspect of my page.

Any help much appreciated.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['book_url']))
{
   $sql = "
SELECT articles.id, articles.order_ref, articles.art_title, articles.art_book, articles.art_url, book.id AS bookid, book.book_name AS book_name, book.book_url AS book_url
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN book ON articles.art_book = book.id
WHERE book_name = \"" .$_GET['book_url'] . "\"
ORDER BY id ASC
";
    // then do the query, etc....
} 

$results = $db->query($sql);

if($results->num_rows) {
    While($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo "

        ////////Show Stuff

        ";
        ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: Consider using a templating engine such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to make this separation nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the code and the HTML by putting the code in `<?php ?>`. Then, in your HTML you can have short code snippets that print the work you did in the code sections. Like this (there might be a syntax error or two, I don't have Apache to test):

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];

function stuff() {
    // this would normally be long and complicated
    return "stuff";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- try to keep these short  so you can focus on design-->
    <h1>The name is: <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
    <h1>The stuff is: <?php echo stuff(); ?></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can use a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) which will provide a templating system.

Comment: Definately the way forward with Bens method. Not sure how I can my code working though with that method.

Comment: @shimmy instead of directly `echo`ing the table or whatever you're trying to make, save it to a variable (even if that variable is a string of html). Then you can do the method. I do want to reiterate @tadman 's warning. It'll be pretty easy for a user to **erase your database** just by manipulating the URL they visit if you leave it that way. Use PDO; it's pretty easy to get started, and relatively safe.